# Can't connect to EC2 via TCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, port, tcp

My Ubuntu 19.04 EC2 instance has security group with inbound and unbound rules set to all protocols, all ports and `0.0.0.0/0` IP range.

I can connect to it with SSH on port 22 and with http on port 80, using Windows `Test-NetConnection`. I run an app on the VM which listens on port 5000, but I couldn't connect to it from my local computer.

Thanks to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/397901/997789) I run a testable process that listens on port 5000 on my VM.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-82:~$ nc -4 -k -l -v localhost 5000
Listening on [localhost] (family 2, port 5000)
```

Calling `curl localhost:5000` on another terminal produces an expected output

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-82:~$ nc -4 -k -l -v localhost 5000
Listening on [localhost] (family 2, port 5000)
Connection from localhost 51424 received!
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
Accept: */*
```

However doing calling `Test-NetConnection` or `Invoke-WebRequest` from my local computer to that machine and port 5000 fails immedietaly (no timeout). The listening process also doesn't print that it received any new connections.

```
(base) PS C:\Users\Konrad> Test-NetConnection **.**.***.** -port 5000 -v
WARNING: TCP connect to (**.**.***.** : 5000) failed
VERBOSE: **.**.***.**.in-addr.arpa
VERBOSE: **.**.***.**.in-addr.arpa
VERBOSE: Perform operation 'Invoke CimMethod' with following parameters, ''methodName' = QueryIsolationType,'className'
 = MSFT_NetAddressFilter,'namespaceName' = root\standardcimv2'.
VERBOSE: Operation 'Invoke CimMethod' complete.


ComputerName           : **.**.***.**
RemoteAddress          : **.**.***.**
RemotePort             : 5000
InterfaceAlias         : Wi-Fi
SourceAddress          : **.**.***.**
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 42 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False
```

Real IPs have been replaced.

What am I missing?

Comment: Usually all aws linux ec2 will be accessed by ssh using key pem file, did you config the access key or you trying to access in a different way?

Comment: You are listening on localhost, you need to listen on the external interface

Comment: @Krismorte I did use private key for that (ssh -i "private_key.pem" address)

Comment: @AlexMoore I'm sorry for my ignorance, but I haven't done that before. Could you please elaborate on that? What could I do?

Comment: Try removing the term localhost on the listening netcat command.

Comment: @AlexMoore Thank you, it works. Please consider adding an answer with some explanation and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue you are encountering with your testing is that on the netcat (nc) command you are setting to listen for connections you are specifying localhost, meaning it will only listen on that localhost interface and any connections coming in from outside it won't be listening on and so it will simply reset the connection, which is what you are seeing.

Instead you can remove the localhost entry on the nc command and it will bind to all interfaces and at that point it should work externally.

For example:

> `nc -4 -k -l -v 5000`